# Listbox control throws null exception upon selection of item

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox, postback

I am creating a web application in asp.net 4.0

I have a web-form in which there is a ListBox control which adds a string list on `Page_Load` event. If I select any list item from ListBox and want to compute it by using `Listbox.SelectedValue` it throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception on `Listbox.SelectedValue`.

By using "QuickWatch" (in Visual studio 2010) i did some findings that i can get value by giving index (say `Listbox.Items[2]`) but i got null or -1 if i use `Listbox.SelectedValue` or `Listbox.SelectedIndex`

My problem is that why ListBox control is showing null exception error upon selection of item as this Listbox is not empty?

Comment: Its not the listbox. *Your* code is throwing that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of the situation you are checking `Listbox.SelectedValue` after `Page_Load` has re-populated the `ListBox` so the SelectedIndex is reset i.e `-1`.
and then you're trying to check the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex` in the event handler,so it will be `-1`.

**Suggestions:**
 1. Populate ListBox on first time Page_Load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!IsPostBack) 
  {
    //Bind it once on first time page load
    MyListbox.DatSource = SqlDataSource1();
    MyListbox.DataBind();
  }
}
```

2. Then after handling the event repopulate the `MyListBox`.
 3. You should make a `protected` method for populating `ListBox`.

**Note:** "null exception" is due to the fact that no item is selected i.e `-1` (which is actually reset on Page_Load)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are binding the `ListBox` on postback to it's `DataSource`, am i right? Then the ListBox will lose his `SelectedValue` (even the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event will not be triggered).

Instead you should databind only on the initial load and check the [`IsPostback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property:

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
        // pseudo code: 
        ListBox1.DatSource = GetYourDataSource();
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' pseudo code: '
        ListBox1.DatSource = GetYourDataSource()
        ListBox1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick helping post. i was binding on Page_Load event. This problem waste my whole day. Thanks again!